# Data Driven Development Definition

Tags: c#, data-driven

I am working on a real-time data historian that collects data, generates its structure (using C# Reflection), creates its corresponding tables in the database and then stores the data.
So, objects collected from server don't have corresponding CRUD but I use a generic DAL (using generic objects with C#).

Can this be called Data Driven Development? I am having a hard finding a convenient definition.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065584/what-is-data-driven-programming

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065584/what-is-data-driven-programming?rq=1

Comment: @TimCastelijns i'm pretty sure that is about data driven programming, and not about Data Driven Development. Both are very different principles. Besides this, i think this question should be on programmers.stackoverflow rather than here